# Sheldon Brown's writing?

Tags: maintenance

This question has been nagging me for ages.

I've read a lot of Sheldon Brown's site and actually tend to use bikes from the 70s-80s because they're more economical for daily use and especially for a student like me. But I've noticed that *some* of his opinions can be controversial (his discussion of "lawyer lips"), can fly in the face of industry practices (that all leather saddles, 'properly cared for', are better than any plastic saddle), questionable (that the Peugeot UO-8 makes for the greatest touring bike of all time) and then, sometimes, his opinions seem on a troll level, which I can't think of any examples off the top of my head, but have caught myself falling prey to them. A lot of his material is either very enlightening (his discussion of brake usage) or helpful in that you simply can't find the topic anywhere else on the web.

So the question is, is Sheldon Brown's site really the one-stop for all knowledge pertaining especially to older bicycles, or should he be taken simply as a prolific writer who wrote on a great many topics and should be taken with a large grain of salt? I guess the real question is, how much do bike mechanics especially and others depend on his work, or is it simply a convenient online resource for people new to the sport?

Comment: I really can't imagine what comments you thought seemed on a troll level, or why he needs to be taken with a grain of salt. I'd love to see an example of what you mean. His knowledge of bicycles is truly encyclopedic and he's considered an authority on almost all things bicycle by many cyclists, including me.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'll post it when I find them. Maybe not troll, as trolling requires malicious intent, but definitely not a good idea to follow.

Comment: @CareyGregory A lot of authorities have a few questionable ideas. You can take some things with a grain of salt while still regarding him as a great authority on most things. The examples in the question like leather saddles are fair, and there's more like that. He says there's no use for valve caps on presta valves, but [the community here seems to disagree](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/1157/634).

Comment: I think Sheldon would encourage people to read everything with a critical eye and to make up their own minds about what works for them.

Comment: I think the only problem I have with his content is that in some ways it has become a bit dated. Is there any chance that his stuff could be turned into a wiki so that it could continue to be updated?

Comment: @Kibbee His site is being maintained and updated.

Comment: @Jefromi Well sure. He's an authority, not a god. Everything any "authority" says should be considered with critical thought and not just blind acceptance. But I'm not so sure the valve cap thing is a good example. The community opinion on that seems to be mixed, and the opinions disagreeing with Sheldon don't sway me. In any case, even if he's dead wrong on that it's a pretty minor thing. The sum total of his work far outweighs any single issue he wrote about. I think Zenbike summed it up very well.

Comment: @CareyGregory Exactly: he's an authority, not a god, so some things he says should be taken with a grain of salt, or at least healthy skepticism.

Comment: @CareyGregory While some of it is still being updated, some of it has fallen out of date. For instance, looking at the [tire sizing](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) page, it says nothing about 650b size tires now being somewhat popular on mountain bikes, only that it was used on "some older Raleigh and Schwinn mountain bikes".  His pages also say very little about 11 speed cassettes, even though they are becoming more popular, and probably aren't going to disappear.  Those are just a couple small examples, but I'm sure there's many more instances.

Comment: This question feels like a "[rant in disguise](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" to me and might be better discussed in [The Velodrome](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome).

Comment: @Kibbee I feel like most of what the site is was very valid in the 90s, somewhat updated in the 00s, but not by SB, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @jimirings Sorry, I tried to give clear and concise points and stay on topic. What do you think can improve in my question?

Comment: @JFA I don't think that the rant is the only problem with it. It's fairly open-ended and subjective. If you take a look at the descriptions of a constructive subjective questions on that same dont-ask page you'll see that it doesn't really fit. That's not to say it's not an *interesting* question. I actually find it very intriguing. I just think that the chat room would be a much better venue for it. Anyway, I've voted to close. It's in the hands of the community now.

Comment: @jimirings I think most things bicycle SE related are subjective, and this not more than others. "What bicycle should I get?" is just one that comes up a lot. Also, the community seems to find this question interesting.

Comment: @JFA I also think that it's an interesting question. That's why I recommended moving to chat rather than simply voting to close. I just think it's too open ended and subjective for the SE format. "What bicycle should I get?" questions are almost always always closed. Perhaps I'm wrong though. That's why we have the voting system. Anyway, this exchange about what constitutes a good question is getting long and would also be better continued in Meta or chat.

Comment: On the subject of leather saddles, a properly fitting and broken in leather saddle was as comfortable as any modern saddle.

Answer (score 15):

Sheldon Brown was a good man, a good cyclist, and he spent an inordinate amount of time writing answers for everybody to questions that every new cyclist has.

In a lot of ways, his answers were pretty dead on. However, like any person with the energy and commitment that Mr. Brown showed with his site, he was very opinionated on a number of issues which are controversial now.

Because he was also among the first cyclists to use the internet to spread his ideas and knowledge to anyone willing to listen, his ideas are often treated as canonical, even when time and science have moved on.

As with any science, new ideas and equipment overtake the old, and new methodologies, for fitting, for bike construction, and for fitness are tested, and either adopted or discarded.

There are cyclists who adhere to what Mr. Brown said on any topic, regardless of the evidence to the contrary which is available now. But then, there are dogmatics in any religion, and cycling is a religion for many.  And if cycling was a religion, then Mr. Brown was its first, or at least best known, Internet age missionary.

He deserves respect for his efforts, but not dogmatic adherence to his viewpoints.

Try his ideas and use what works.  If something doesn't work for you, discard it, and find something that does.  He would be the first to tell you to think for yourself.

Comment: Very well stated.  He's a knowledgeable guy (or guys -- not sure how many people have actually written for the site) but has opinions like anyone else, and is generally writing with a particular perspective (more on-road than off-road, eg), so one need not (and should not) accept everything he says as the gospel truth.

Comment: No disrespect to him intended. Maybe I didn't make it clear that I do think a lot of his ideas, especially his introductory articles, are spot on and make great resources, and I frequently link them to people I think can improve. But I do feel some of it is opinion based, and like all opinions, including those of the top experts in their field, his are not 100%.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Sheldon passed away some years ago, so I don't know whether anyone is updating that site anymore,but if it's Sheldon, it would be divine inspiration.

Comment: Lol no it's John Allen and someone else, but I don't think a lot has really changed. I'd kind of like to take all his material and put it in a a modern Web 2.0 format, but I don't know what the licensing on his stuff is.

Comment: I know, that there is Russian community site, that translated his texts and publishing them. If I remember right, they got permission to do it from Sheldon Brown. So just access John Allen, and I sure he will greatly accept your initiative.

Answer (score 1):

Every theory in science can be discussed. No one can say something absolute - even things, that looks now like "the only truth", can be overridden the next year (or even before).
Sheldon Brown was a great bicyclist, that knew the theory and physics of bikes. He also was a rider with lot of experience in it. He wrote his own feelings and practice. His opinion may be discussed (especially in such subjective things like saddle), and it is in some books. Yet his posts are highly honored by many cyclists.

Comment: I've noticed that. What I'm saying is, after 5-6 years of reading his work, I'm starting to feel like it's more a cyclist bible than scientific fact.

Comment: He is writing much from his experience, so it have to be feel like a bible, but there are some scientific facts too. BTW yesterday I found another blog, that very recommends Brook saddles :)

Comment: Do you still have the link? :P

Comment: @JFA it's russian site. He's writing only from his experience, with roughly these words: "If it will be about a great race, I would assemble a steel touring bike of Shimano XT class, maybe with a carbon fork, and for sure with a leather brooks seat." (For russian speaking: http://kotovski.net/gibridyi-kakie-dlya-chego-i-dlya-kogo/)