# Maintenance for an idle bicycle kept indoors?

Tags: maintenance

I have recently bought a six-speed transmission bicycle, basic yet the latest one. But owing to my busy schedule I am not able to go for a ride on it, and the cycle is always left idle at one place.

So, I wanted to know how I can at least maintain my bicycle, so that it doesn’t rust and stays healthy.

Bike is always kept indoors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7577/maintaining-an-old-bike-properly?rq=1

Comment: The answer seems to be found out by one. Not everyone searches  with the same keys right?-__-

Comment: Your original title was not very informative, and things like "Thanks" and smilies are generally regarded as "noise" (pardon the expression) that adds nothing to the question. So is complaining about edits (especially when my edit went through review), for that matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining an old bike properly](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7577/maintaining-an-old-bike-properly)

Comment: Being in a garage is not ideal, for two reasons:  1) There may be petroleum fumes in the air that attack tires, brake pads, and other components.  2) Many garages get quite hot in the summer, and heat causes the bearing grease to run out.

Answer (score 8):

A lightly-used bike stored indoors in a dry (not humid) environment does not need much special maintenance. Just keep it clean with light lubrication on the chain.

The tires will slowly lose pressure. A bike left sitting for a long time on one spot on un-inflated tires is probably not good for the tires or tubes. Keep some air pressure in the tires or hang the bike up off the floor if you can.

Comment: Lately I have been pumping air into the tyres... any idea how often it should be done?

Comment: Often enough to keep the tires at least semi inflated :) It will depend on how much air you put in them each time. Different tires/tubes lose air at different rates, temperature probably makes a difference too.

Comment: Yes, in summers its better to push less air in.. although I fill em up completely each time..irrespective of the weather.

Comment: Any further suggestions bud?

Answer (score 1):

As @Argenti Apparatus said, it is crucial for tires and tubes to keep them inflated. 
Additionally, if you cannot hang it, at least change the tire - floor contact point by rolling the wheel.
Protect rubber parts from the sun - keep the bike in the shade or cover it. You can also spray it with i.e. silicone compound for rubber parts.

Clean and grease your chain. There is often enough humidity in the air to make not oiled chain to corrode.

Make sure that bearings are greased. If not - repack and grease.

I would personally oil brake and shifting cables.

Use proper bike lock or even thick chain that you would not normally use and check periodically against theft issues.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to ruin a bike is to leave it outside in all weathers.

**Answer:** Park it inside, or in a garage.  If you don't have anything like that, at least park it under cover out of the weather.

Comment: It is in the garage!.. wait I’ll mention it.